# 2d ArrayLists - Why does adding an object to one sublist add the same object to all sublists?

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

In Java, I am creating a football fixture generator for a league containing 4 teams.

I have a 2d Array List called 'matchDays', which contains 6 match day Array Lists. Each match day contains 2 fixture objects.

I am attempting to iterate through matchDays, and for each match day, add 2 fixture objects from a list of all possible fixtures that I have created separately. The problem is that when I add a fixture to match day 1, it is also added to match days 2 through 6.

The following code is from a test case I wrote that highlights the problem I am having:

```
@Test
public void arrayListTest() {
    FixtureGenerator fixGen = new FixtureGenerator();

    // Generate all possible fixtures
    List<Fixture> fixtures = fixGen.generateFixtures();

    // Create list of all 4 participating teams
    List<Club> clubs = fixGen.createListOfClubs();

    // Create 6 lists (match days) to store 2 fixtures in each
    List<List<Fixture>> matchDays = fixGen.createMatchDaysList(clubs); 

    matchDays.get(0).add(fixtures.get(0));
    System.out.println("Match day 1, fixture 1: " + matchDays.get(0).get(0).getHomeTeam() + 
            " v " + matchDays.get(0).get(0).getAwayTeam());
    System.out.println("Match day 2, fixture 1: " + matchDays.get(1).get(0).getHomeTeam() + 
            " v " + matchDays.get(1).get(0).getAwayTeam());
    System.out.println("Match day 3, fixture 1: " + matchDays.get(2).get(0).getHomeTeam() + 
            " v " + matchDays.get(2).get(0).getAwayTeam());
}
```

This code produces the following console output:

```
Match day 1, fixture 1: Team A v Team B
Match day 2, fixture 1: Team A v Team B
Match day 3, fixture 1: Team A v Team B
```

If I have only added fixture 'Team A v Team B' to match day 1, how is it appearing in match day 2 and 3?

Comment: Looks like you're using the same object references on every List of your program.

Comment: Impossible to answer because we cannot see how the lists are being initialized. But it's probable you're using the same lists for each.

Comment: Sorry Dave I was trying not to post too much code. Luiggi, I don't understand the problem. Does matchDays.get(0) and matchDays.get(1) not return 2 different lists? Thanks for the fast replies.

Comment: @RyanDeery: they could return the same list (and probably do) if you stored the same list at both indices (which you probably did). Why don't you post the code you were asked to post?

Comment: @JBNizet, my class was over 200 lines and I couldn't find the problem. Thanks guys I have resolved the issue. I was using a for loop to populate the matchDays Array List with 6 references to the same matchDay List. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem code. I was populating the matchDays list with the same reference as stated by @LuiggiMendoza and @DaveNewton like this:

```
List<List<Fixture>> matchdays = new ArrayList<List<Fixture>>();
List<Fixture> matchday = new ArrayList<Fixture>();
for (int i = 0; i < noOfMatchDays; i++) {
    matchdays.add(matchday);
}
```

All I had to do was change it to the following so each match day is represented by it's own list object:

```
List<List<Fixture>> matchdays = new ArrayList<List<Fixture>>();

for(int i = 0; i < noOfMatchDays; i++){
    matchdays.add(new ArrayList<Fixture>());
}
```

Thanks for the answers everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29): " The returned list is backed by this list, so non-structural changes in the returned list are reflected in this list, and vice-versa."